# HAVING COUNT(*) with MAX() sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a statement that will show the `first_name`, `last_name`, `course_no`, `description` for the `instructor` that `teaches` the most java courses. My `max` statement shows the maximum number of courses however, when I executed the complete statement then I got no results. 
Below is the Query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, course_no, description
FROM(
    SELECT i.first_name, i.last_name, c.course_no, c.description
    FROM instructor i INNER JOIN section s
    ON i.instructor_id = s.instructor_id
    JOIN course c ON c.course_no = s.course_no
    WHERE c.description LIKE '%Java%') 
GROUP BY first_name, last_name, course_no, description
HAVING COUNT(*) =
    (SELECT MAX(course_count)
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, COUNT(*) As course_count
           FROM(
               SELECT i.first_name, i.last_name, c.course_no, c.description
               FROM instructor i INNER JOIN section s
               ON i.instructor_id = s.instructor_id
               JOIN course c ON c.course_no = s.course_no
               WHERE c.description LIKE '%Java%')
           GROUP BY first_name, last_name));
```

Comment: Might be better to use your MAX() sub select to get the instructor id and then use a simple WHERE clause to filter on all the instructor's courses

Comment: Why do you want `course_no` and `description`? Because what if the Instructor named John Doe for example teach Intro to Java and Intermediate Java which one do you want to display? Or do you want just to count instructor that taught Java whether Intro or not? Or you want it separately?

Comment: I would like them all to display. The name should be repeated and then list out each course_no and description.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch between your outer query and the subquery in your `HAVING` clause: the former has `GROUP BY first_name, last_name, course_no, description`, the latter only `GROUP BY first_name, last_name`. Naturally, you won't generally find any 4-tuples of the former columns with as many rows as the most common pair of the latter columns.

Comment: I'm sorry I am fairly new to this and don't completely understand your answer.

Comment: @kabel: Which part of it don't you understand? (By the way -- how did you build your query? Did you start with some existing queries, and try to tweak them to what you needed?)

Comment: I'm confused on what the difference of the group by fields causes. I built the statement I first started with an initial statement that brought up all of the courses and instructors that taught a course containing java and went from there.

Comment: @kabel: It causes the `COUNT(*)`'s to be different (since in the subquery it counts the number of records for a given full name, while in the outer query it counts the number of records for a given full name *and course*). Since your `HAVING` clause asks for the `COUNT(*)`'s to be the same, it doesn't work.